# why xpath is returning text outside html tags?

Tags: html, ruby, parsing, xpath, nokogiri

I am working with a document which have some `text` outside `<html>` tag. When I read data inside body it also returns the text which is not even in html tag.

```
page_text = Nokogiri::HTML(open(file_path)).xpath("//body").text
p page_text
```

**Output:**

`"WARC/1.0\nWARC-Type: response\nWARC-Date: 2012-02-11T04:48:01Z\nWARC-TREC-ID: clueweb12-0000tw-13-04988\nWARC-IP-Address: 184.85.26.15\nWARC-Payload-Digest: sha1:PNCB5NNAA766RLLISZ6ODV3FJZBCATKR\nWARC-Target-URI: http://www.allchocolate.com/health/basics/\nWARC-Record-ID: \nContent-Type: application/http; msgtype=response\nContent-Length: 14577\n\n\n\n\n    sample document\n\n\n    hello world\n\n"`

**Document:**

```
WARC/1.0
WARC-Type: response
WARC-Date: 2012-02-11T04:48:01Z
WARC-TREC-ID: clueweb12-0000tw-13-04988
WARC-IP-Address: 184.85.26.15
WARC-Payload-Digest: sha1:PNCB5NNAA766RLLISZ6ODV3FJZBCATKR
WARC-Target-URI: http://www.allchocolate.com/health/basics/
WARC-Record-ID: <urn:uuid:ff32c863-5066-4f51-802a-f31d4af074d5>
Content-Type: application/http; msgtype=response
Content-Length: 14577

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>sample document</title>
</head>
<body>
    hello world
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please read "[mcve]". Don't use an image to show us your expected output. Links rot then break and when that does your question won't make sense. Instead copy/paste the information into your question and format it properly for readability. You need to strip the non-HTML from your source prior to passing it to Nokogiri. It has no idea what the header information is so you're just confusing it.

Comment: @theTinMan Thank you for suggestion, I have edited my question.

Answer (score 2):

Nokogiri is trying to parse the file contents as a HTML document, but it isn’t a valid document. It is a text document that just happens to contain in it a HTML document. Of course Nokogiri doesn’t know this, and it isn’t able to pick out that part that is HTML by itself, so it tries to parse the whole thing. Since it is not valid HTML, this produces errors.

As it parses, Nokogiri attempts to fix these errors as best it can, but that doesn’t work in this case, and results in the strange looking output you see here.

In particular, when Nokogiri sees the text before the HTML, it assumes that it should be part of the HTML document body. So it creates and injects `html` and `body` elements into the document, before adding the text as a child of this `body`.

Later it sees the actual `<body>` tag, but since it knows it already has a `body` element, and that there can only be one such element, it ignores it.

You need to make sure that you only provide valid HTML (or as close as you can to valid — the error correction can fix small things). You will probably need to pre-process your files in some way to remove the extra text at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly leading text is a problem, but not trailing text. XML is a highly structured language, and applying an XML parser to HTML means at the very least that you have to have valid HTML. If you don't have valid HTML, then you get whatever Nokogiri spits out.

It looks to me like Nokogiri wraps the whole thing in a default root node, then returns all the text nodes therein, essentially ignoring the `//body` xpath. Interestingly, if you wrap your text in a `div` and search for the xpath `//div`, no problems, so that might suggest a solution.

It seems like Nokogiri considers `//body` to be equal to the root node.  Ah!  Maybe Nokogiri uses `<body>` for the root node.  Nope: the xpath `/body//body` doesn't work.

**Response to comment:**

You could use a regex to search for the `<body>` tag then insert a div tag. But searching html with a simple regex will be a fragile solution, and it won't work in all cases.

By the way, you can see how Nokogiri handles text outside of tags by parsing a document that only has the text: hello world, then printing out all the nodes that Nokogiri finds:

```
require 'nokogiri'

nodes = Nokogiri::HTML(open('html.html')).xpath('//*')

nodes.each do |node|
  puts node.name
end

--output:--
html
body
p
```

So Nokogiri wraps the text in three tags.

Or, better yet, you can parse your document and print it out as html:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('./html.html'))
puts doc.to_html

--output:--
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html><body><p>WARC/1.0
WARC-Type: response
WARC-Date: 2012-02-11T04:48:01Z
WARC-TREC-ID: clueweb12-0000tw-13-04988
WARC-IP-Address: 184.85.26.15
WARC-Payload-Digest: sha1:PNCB5NNAA766RLLISZ6ODV3FJZBCATKR
WARC-Target-URI: http://www.allchocolate.com/health/basics/
WARC-Record-ID: <uuid:ff32c863-5066-4f51-802a-f31d4af074d5>
Content-Type: application/http; msgtype=response
Content-Length: 14577




    <title>sample document</title>


    hello world


</uuid:ff32c863-5066-4f51-802a-f31d4af074d5></p></body></html>
```

That means you can get `hello world` like this:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('./html.html'))
title = doc.at_xpath('//title')
puts title.next.text.strip

--output:--
hello world
```

Another approach is to get rid of the non-html content before parsing with Nokogiri:

```
require 'nokogiri'

infile = File.open('html.html')
non_html = infile.gets(sep="\n\n")
html = infile.gets(nil)  #Slurp the rest of the file

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
puts doc.at_xpath('//body').text.strip

--output:--
hello world
```

That assumes there's always a blank line separating the non-html content from the html content.

Comment: So what's the solution ?

Comment: See additions to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

First of all @7stud answer is spot on that you can break you file on `\n\n` but 
in my documents collection it's not always `\n\n` before actual html code.

So using the same idea i have came with another workaround that to remove all the text before `html` start tag using regex and then pass it to `Nokogiri` to parse.

```
file = File.read(file_path).to_s
file = file.sub(/.*?(?=<html)/im,"")
page = Nokogiri::HTML(file)
```

Now it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple to preprocess the content before passing it to Nokogiri:

```
require 'nokogiri'

text = '
WARC/1.0
WARC-Type: response
WARC-Date: 2012-02-11T04:48:01Z
WARC-TREC-ID: clueweb12-0000tw-13-04988
WARC-IP-Address: 184.85.26.15
WARC-Payload-Digest: sha1:PNCB5NNAA766RLLISZ6ODV3FJZBCATKR
WARC-Target-URI: http://www.allchocolate.com/health/basics/
WARC-Record-ID: <urn:uuid:ff32c863-5066-4f51-802a-f31d4af074d5>
Content-Type: application/http; msgtype=response
Content-Length: 14577

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>sample document</title>
</head>
<body>
    hello world
</body>
</html>
'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(text[/<!DOCTYPE.+/m])
doc.to_html # => "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd\">\n<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\" xml:lang=\"en\" lang=\"en\">\n<head>\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\">\n    <title>sample document</title>\n</head>\n<body>\n    hello world\n</body>\n</html>\n"
```

The trick is:

```
text[/<!DOCTYPE.+/m]
```

which tells Ruby to look through the text and return all the text from `<!DOCTYPE` to the end of the string, which is valid HTML.